# Is it possible to speed up sorting algorithm with Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, sorting, parallel.foreach

I am trying to understand how the "Parallel.ForEach" function works. I have read the MSDN about it and as an overall understanding it seems that, the more computations you put in the loop the faster it goes in comparison to a normal foreach loop.

Current computer has 4 Cores.
*(I will have installed my 24 core computer in two days.)*

However I think I need some expertise insight in this. I have a sorting algorithm that do a sort in about 10 seconds on 1 core.

I have put a complete code where I do it on one core and where I do it in a: Parallel.ForEach loop with 4 cores.

I simply wonder if it is possible to speed up this sort using more cores in any possible way?

**Running testsortFunction() produces below result:**

[image]

```
    void testsortFunction()
    {
        String resultstring1 = ""; String resultstring2 = "";
        resultstring1 = sortingtestBENCHMARKS(false);
        resultstring2 = sortingtestBENCHMARKS(true);

        MessageBox.Show(resultstring1 + "\n\n" + resultstring2);
    }
    String sortingtestBENCHMARKS(bool useParallel)
    {
        List<String> sortedLIST = new List<String>(); 
        List<String> minusLIST = new List<String>(); 
        List<String> plusLIST = new List<String>(); 
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        //Add 3 million elements
        for (double i = 0; i < 1000000; i += 1)
        {
            plusLIST.Add(i + ",awb/aje" + " - " + "ddfas/asa" + " - " + "asoo/qwa");
        }
        for (double i = 1; i < 2000000; i += 1)
        {
            minusLIST.Add("-" + i + ",awb/aje" + " - " + "ddfas/asa" + " - " + "asoo/qwa");
        }

        //Do the sorting!
        if (useParallel == false)
        {
            stopwatch.Start();
            sortedLIST = sortLIST(minusLIST, plusLIST); //11 seconds
            stopwatch.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            stopwatch.Start();
            Parallel.ForEach("dummy", (c) =>
            {
                sortedLIST = sortLIST(minusLIST, plusLIST); //32 seconds
            });
            stopwatch.Stop();
        }
        return "Elapsed Times in seconds(Using Parallel: " + useParallel + "):\n\n" + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds; //10.57 seconds
    }
    List<String> sortLIST(List<String> minusLIST, List<String> plusLIST)
    {
        plusLIST = plusLIST.OrderBy(i => double.Parse(i.Split(',')[0])).ToList();plusLIST.Reverse();
        minusLIST = minusLIST.OrderBy(i => double.Parse(i.Split(',')[0].TrimStart('-'))).ToList();
        plusLIST.AddRange(minusLIST);
        return plusLIST;
    }
```

Comment: Use PLINQ instead, eg `someList.AsParallel().OrderBy(...)`. Parallel sorting algorithms are very different beasts. If every core tried to access every item all CPU time would be wasted in thrashing and locking. To get any performance boost you need to *partition* the data and use one task to sort each partition. The sorted partitions have to be merged at the end.

Comment: This test is severely flawed.  Your `Parallel.ForEach` is doing much more work.

Comment: BTW your test isn't sorting anything in parallel. It's repeating the *same* sort operation, as many times as there are cores

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos oh heck you're right - it's performing one sort for each of the characters in "dummy" -- so it's doing exactly the same thing 5 times. It's doing them in parallel mind you, so it's only just over 3 times slower.

Comment: Use `OrderByDescending` instead of `OrderBy` then `Reverse` -- that will save you a little bit of time.

Comment: BTW why do you use `double.Parse(i.Split(',')[0])` ?? If the text contains European-style decimal separators pass the appropriate CultureInfo object to `double.Parse`. Each string operation results in a new temporary string. This means that your code will generate *3 million extra temporary strings*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it looks like this: `plusLIST.Add(i + ",awb/aje" + " - " + "ddfas/asa" + " - " + "asoo/qwa");` and it's 6 million - 2 parts per element, and there are a 3 million elements

Comment: @canton7 in that case, a regex to parse that long string will result in a couple more orders of magnitude improvement in performance, even without parallelization

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach("dummy", (c) => ...` means, "_for each character in `dummy`, do ...; if possible in parallel_". Now, since `dummy` has 5 characters, you are sorting the list 5 times. Even if this is happening in some parallel fashion, how much do you think you are gaining when sorting the list 5 times compared to sorting the list just once?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not sure it would - the regex parsing will allocate. You'd have to profile it.

Comment: @canton7 the Regex object is thread-safe so there's no need to create a lot of them. A single regex object can be used by multiple threads.  I *have* profiled this parsing some pretty big log files. Simply moving from splits to Regex reduced memory usage, garbage collection so much that parallelization had little more to offer. When you go eg from minutes to a few seconds, parallelizing isn't that important

Comment: I wasn't referring to parallelisation. I'll run some benchmarks now...

Comment: By the way, you are not just sorting 5 times, you are growing your `plusList` each time (`plusLIST.AddRange`), making any subsequent sort slower due to more elements being in the list.

Comment: And finally, remember, each invocation of `sortLIST` will possibly happen in parallel, with each concurrently running invocation of `sortLIST` trying to add elements to the same `plusLIST` or trying to access elements in `plusList` in some manner while another invocation of `sortLIST` is modifying it. Wonderful chaos will ensue, because a simple List<T> is not thread-safe (it is not safe to modify a simple List<T> in a concurrent manner)

Comment: Thank you for all comments. I read them and try to understand. I tried: someList.AsParallel().OrderBy(...) but are not sure if that did any specific difference. I am not sure what "dummy" does. I just filled out the arguments since I have nothing to pass but that seemed like a bad idéa. 5 characters.

Comment: This should help with the concept. Link to example of [multi-threaded bottom up merge sort](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148025/multithreaded-bottom-up-merge-sort).

Comment: You can replace `OrderBy` with `OrderByDescending` instead of doing a separate call to `Reverse`.

Comment: Yes: AsParallel().OrderByDescending and then reverse took only 4 seconds instead of about 8 seconds. That was a good improvement!

Comment: Yeah, I think that `sortList` method could just be one line: `return plusLIST.OrderByDescending(i => double.Parse(i.Split(',')[0])).Concat(minusLIST.OrderBy(i => double.Parse(i.Split(',')[0].TrimStart('-')))).ToList();`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos using regex (cached in a static field) doubled the time to sort

Comment: That one line of code was much nicer. I changed it to that also. Thanks!

Comment: One idéa that I have but are not sure of. If we were to divide the entire lists into small containers where one is: >= 0 && < 1, >= 1 && < 2 etc etc etc. And then sort each container by assigning one core for each container and in the end sum up all values. Would this be a good idéa and how would this be possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran some benchmarks, and managed to speed it up by a factor of 2...

```
public List<String> ParallelSort()
{
    var result = new List<string>(plusLIST.Count + minusLIST.Count);

    var t1 = Task.Run(() => plusLIST.AsParallel().OrderByDescending(i => int.Parse(i.Split(',')[0])));
    var t2 = Task.Run(() => minusLIST.AsParallel().OrderBy(i => int.Parse(i.Split(',')[0].TrimStart('-'))));
    Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);

    result.AddRange(t1.Result);
    result.AddRange(t2.Result);
    return result;
}
```

Here's the benchmark, using BenchmarkDotNet.

(I reduced the list size by a factor of 10, because benchmarking takes a long time and I want to go home tonight).

```
|                 Method |      Mean |    Error |    StdDev |    Median | Gen 0/1k Op | Gen 1/1k Op | Gen 2/1k Op | Allocated Memory/Op |
|----------------------- |----------:|---------:|----------:|----------:|------------:|------------:|------------:|--------------------:|
|                 OPSort | 142.35 ms | 5.150 ms | 14.693 ms | 137.40 ms |  29000.0000 |   1000.0000 |           - |           135.99 MB |
| OPSortByDescendingLazy | 118.19 ms | 2.672 ms |  7.752 ms | 117.01 ms |  29000.0000 |   1000.0000 |           - |           127.32 MB |
|   SlightlyParallelSort | 122.62 ms | 3.063 ms |  8.538 ms | 120.45 ms |  29000.0000 |   1000.0000 |           - |           127.32 MB |
|           ParallelSort |  71.37 ms | 2.190 ms |  6.389 ms |  70.30 ms |  28000.0000 |   1000.0000 |           - |           148.63 MB |
|              RegexSort | 250.80 ms | 4.887 ms |  7.315 ms | 251.70 ms |  32000.0000 |   1000.0000 |           - |           145.99 MB |
```

And the code:

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class Tests
{
    private List<String> minusLIST = new List<string>(100000);
    private List<String> plusLIST = new List<string>(200000);

    [IterationSetup]
    public void IterationSetup()
    {
        plusLIST.Clear();
        minusLIST.Clear();

        //Add 3 million elements
        for (double i = 0; i < 100000; i += 1)
        {
            plusLIST.Add(i + ",awb/aje" + " - " + "ddfas/asa" + " - " + "asoo/qwa");
        }
        for (double i = 1; i < 200000; i += 1)
        {
            minusLIST.Add("-" + i + ",awb/aje" + " - " + "ddfas/asa" + " - " + "asoo/qwa");
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public List<String> OPSort()
    {
        plusLIST = plusLIST.OrderBy(i => double.Parse(i.Split(',')[0])).ToList(); plusLIST.Reverse();
        minusLIST = minusLIST.OrderBy(i => double.Parse(i.Split(',')[0].TrimStart('-'))).ToList();
        plusLIST.AddRange(minusLIST);
        return plusLIST;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public List<String> OPSortByDescendingLazy()
    {
        var result = new List<string>(plusLIST.Count + minusLIST.Count);

        result.AddRange(plusLIST.OrderByDescending(i => int.Parse(i.Split(',')[0])));
        result.AddRange(minusLIST.OrderBy(i => int.Parse(i.Split(',')[0].TrimStart('-'))));
        return result;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public List<String> SlightlyParallelSort()
    {
        var result = new List<string>(plusLIST.Count + minusLIST.Count);

        var t1 = Task.Run(() => plusLIST.OrderByDescending(i => int.Parse(i.Split(',')[0])));
        var t2 = Task.Run(() => minusLIST.OrderBy(i => int.Parse(i.Split(',')[0].TrimStart('-'))));
        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);

        result.AddRange(t1.Result);
        result.AddRange(t2.Result);
        return result;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public List<String> ParallelSort()
    {
        var result = new List<string>(plusLIST.Count + minusLIST.Count);

        var t1 = Task.Run(() => plusLIST.AsParallel().OrderByDescending(i => int.Parse(i.Split(',')[0])));
        var t2 = Task.Run(() => minusLIST.AsParallel().OrderBy(i => int.Parse(i.Split(',')[0].TrimStart('-'))));
        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);

        result.AddRange(t1.Result);
        result.AddRange(t2.Result);
        return result;
    }

    private static readonly Regex splitRegex = new Regex(@"^(\d+)");
    private static readonly Regex splitWithMinusRegex = new Regex(@"^-(\d+)");

    // To test the suggestion from @PanagiotisKanavos 
    [Benchmark]
    public List<String> RegexSort()
    {
        plusLIST = plusLIST.OrderBy(i => double.Parse(splitRegex.Match(i).Groups[1].Value)).ToList(); plusLIST.Reverse();
        minusLIST = minusLIST.OrderBy(i => double.Parse(splitWithMinusRegex.Match(i).Groups[1].Value)).ToList();
        plusLIST.AddRange(minusLIST);
        return plusLIST;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Tests>();

        Console.WriteLine("========= DONE! ============");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It's probably possible to speed it up more: the next step is to break out a profiler.

Note that your arrays are large enough to be allocated on the Large Object Heap, which is generally bad news. You want to avoid as many of these sorts of allocations as you can, so don't let your lists figure out what size they need to be by themselves.

Comment: Very interesting, I will study your code. I wonder: Task.Run(() => plusLIST.AsParallel. Does this actually use threads on ONE core or will that use the power of for example 24 cores. As I think new Thread() works up to 4 times faster but than starts to be slower as new Thread() works/ is isolated on one core only?

Comment: You can see from the benchmarking that AsParallel() speeds it up a bit. Using Task.Run means I can sort plusLIST and minusLIST at the same time.

Comment: Does AsParallel use more cores(ex: 24 cores) or only more threads on one core? and the same does Task.Run use more cores(ex: 24 cores) or only more threads on one core?

Comment: Threads aren't assigned to core - the OS will schedule threads to cores as it sees fit.

Comment: I see, I remember I did special tests some time ago for that. When I did new Thread() on the 24 cores computer. It only speeded the code up 4 times. After this the speed actually decreased as it never seemed to reach all cores. I am not sure if this does something else and actually use all cores then?

Comment: You'd have to try it and see - I'm not sure how many threads plinq will spin up in this exact case

Comment: canton7, yes I will do that and experiment and see. Thank you very much for your benchmark. It is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

`Parallel.ForEach` is terrific for partionable problems: that is, problems you can split into entirely distinct subproblems. Its first parameter is an enumerable collection with each item in the collection representing a partition.

Sorting a single list of items is *not* partitionable.  Your parallelized code just repeats the sort a whole mess of times.

By the way, consider using the [`list.Sort()` method of dotnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2) for doing your sorts. Very smart people have optimized it. When the items being sorted are not simple strings or scalars, you can provide a comparison function.

Comment: The problem with `List<T>.Sort` is he's sorting by a key derived from his list item. `Enumerable.OrderBy` is smart about keeping a table of the keys, but you don't get any such help with `List<T>.Sort`

Comment: Yes that is true. .Sort() does not work in this case.

Comment: As an ideá can we sort "plusLIST" and "minusLIST" separately on 2 cores for example using any Parallel approach and sum up the sorted list after this. Assuming I would create 100 containers later?